# How to set Character Encoding and Content Type globally in a Java web app?

Tags: java, servlets

I have this piece of code in each Servlet I have:

```
httpServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

Is there any way to set these globally for the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that will interrupt the request and set the Character Encoding and Content Type for all the servlets.

Please have a look at [The Essentials of Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)

- Modifying the request headers and data. You do this by providing a customized version of the request.
- Modifying the response headers and data. You do this by providing a customized version of the response.

---

Sample code directly from [Example: Modifying the Request Character Encoding](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
    ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws
    IOException, ServletException {
    String encoding = selectEncoding(request);
    if (encoding != null){
       //request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
       response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
       //response.setContentType(contentType);
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
 }
 public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws
    ServletException {
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    this.encoding = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
 }
 protected String selectEncoding(ServletRequest request) {
    return (this.encoding);
 }
```